# $E[g(x)f(x)]=0$ for all $g(x)$ implies $f(x)=0$?

Tags: probability

If I have an expected value of a product of two functions, $E[f(x)g(x)]=0$ for any $g(x)$, does it mean $f(x)=0$ ?

Thanks

Comment: What space are you working in? What restrictions do you have on $f$ and $g$?

Comment: $L^2$, and g is bounded and measurable

Comment: **Hint:** Take $g(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: Right, thanks .

Comment: What about sets of measure zero?

Comment: I guess $g(x)=1_{f>0}(x)$ and $g(x)=-1_{f<0}(x)$ becasue the choice f=g is nice but maybe f is not bounded.

Comment: @Kolmo Yes, your idea is better. The condition that $g$ is bounded was added after I wrote my comment.